# Extract everything inside quotation marks but keep quoted content quoted

Tags: regex, string

I have the following case

```
"_,\"'() is a marker of \"'_( ,)\"."
```

and I want to extract this string with Regex such that:

```
_,\"'() marker \"'_( ,)\"
```

matches.

Another example for better readability (however the previous example is more important for the use case)

```
"Test is a marker for 'testing'"
```

which should result in

```
Test marker testing
```

```
G is a abbreviation for "GDP ('Gross Domestic Product')"
```

```
G  abbreviation GDP ('Gross Domestic Product')
```

There are only two options either marker or abbreviation.

My current regex is the following:

```
/(.*)+ is the (father|mother) of (?:"([^,]*)")./
```

But it doesn't work with the first example.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
(\w+) is a (marker|abbreviation) for ("[^"]*?"|'[^']*?')
```

##### R Example

```r
library(stringr)

convert <- function(s) {
  res <- str_match(s, "(\\w+) is a (marker|abbreviation) for (\"[^\"]*?\"|'[^']*?')")
  return <- paste(res[2], res[3], substr(res[4], 2, nchar(res[4])-1))
}

print(convert("Test is a marker for 'testing'"))  # Test marker testing
print(convert("G is a abbreviation for \"GDP ('Gross Domestic Product')\""))  # G abbreviation GDP ('Gross Domestic Product')
```

Also, see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XVE3Ga/1) of the regex

P.S. As most of your questions were about R language, I thought to show an example exactly in R. Hope it is helpful.